# Can we restrict the fields to filter in Products Lookup Dialogs?

Tags: lookup, filters, search, product

[image]

Hi,
In the above image of lookup dialog window of Products object(Standard), I have to filter the records by using *filter by*. Here I want only selected fields to be visible in the dropdown but not all fields.

Products doesn't have Lookup Filter Fields option in Search Layouts

Is it possible in salesforce? If yes, then please suggest me how to do it.

TIA.